# MongoDB Find and Remove Algorithmic Complexity

Tags: algorithm, mongodb, big-o

What is the big-o complexity of MongoDB find operation and remove operation. Say I have n strings in my MongoDB collection - 'abc' and I query the collection 'abc' using abc.find() to get all the elements in abc what is the runtime complexity of this operation?

Also, if I do abc.remove({"string": s}, what would the runtime complexity be for that, given I have n elements in my collection?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question depends on whether an index can be used for the [query criteria](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/) of your `find` or not. If an index can be used, it also depends on the [type of index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes-introduction/):

- If no index can be used, you can bet on O(n).
- In most cases, indexes are [b-trees](http://zhangliyong.github.io/posts/2014/02/19/mongodb-index-internals.html), in which case you can expect O(log n).
- In the special case that a hash index can be used, and provided your query looks for the exact value, it could be O(1).

You can use [`abc.explain()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/) ton analyse the query execution plan  (`COLLSCAN` O(1) vs `IXSCAN` index type specific big-O).

For the removal, of an item in the collection, all indexes must be updated. As you can infer from above, it depends pretty much on how many and what type of indexes refer to this collection.

Comment: If I have no query in my find call and I just need all elements in the database is it still O(n)?

Comment: Yes:  no querry means you browse through all elements.  That's O(n)

Comment: According to https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/explain-results/ the above might have a typo, `COLSCAN` would be O(n) whereas FETCH would be the O(1). This does appear to be correctly stated in the description before the reference to explain.